# Function template compilation error

Tags: c++, templates

The following code

```
template <typename T, class ContainerType>
ContainerType<T>::iterator elementIteratorAt(ContainerType<T> container, size_t index)
{
    return container.end();
}
```

generates a compile error at the function's return type (`ContainerType<T>::iterator`):

> error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Why does it happen and how to write this properly? I'm not even instantiating the template, just compiling.

Comment: That's a function template, not a template function, by the way. Anyway, see [Where and Why Do I Have to Put the Template and Typename Keywords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: @chris: Hm. In my language that certainly is "template function".

Comment: @VioletGiraffe No, it's definitely a *function template*. Similarly, there are *class templates* but no *template classes*

Comment: @Praetorian: maybe you're right for English terminology, I'll read on it. Just explaining why I wrote it the way I did. Makes more sense this way, too. It's a function of a template kind; primarily a function, then a template. Anyway, I still can't make my code compile after reading the question you deem a duplicate.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yeah, sorry about that. Reopened now, there's another problem with your code.

Comment: @Praetorian: P. S. It's embarassing to see that I've already upvoted the linked question and its top rated answer, meaning I've already been down that road some time ago...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That's happened to me a few times too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, `ContainerType<T>::iterator` is a dependent type so you must add the `typename` keyword. Next, `ContainerType` is supposed to be a template, but the template parameter doesn't indicate that. You need a template template parameter.

```
template <typename T, template<class...> class ContainerType>
typename ContainerType<T>::iterator 
    elementIteratorAt(ContainerType<T> container, size_t index)
{
    return container.end();
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70d2dc93239685a5)

I've made the template template parameter variadic because containers in the standard library all have more than one template parameter.

---

As suggested in the comments, you could also simplify it to

```
template <class ContainerType>
typename ContainerType::iterator 
    elementIteratorAt(ContainerType container, size_t index)
{
    return container.end();
}
```

Use `ContainerType::value_type` (will work for standard library containers) if you need access to the element type in the container.

Comment: Oh, the thrills of template programming!

Comment: Or simply `template <class ContainerType>
typename ContainerType::iterator elementIteratorAt(ContainerType container, size_t index)`.

Comment: @Constructor That would work too, but I'm assuming he needs the `T` within the function. I guess you could use `ContainerType::value_type` for that ... oh well

Comment: @Constructor: huh, it didn't occur to me. That works fine, too, since I don't actually need `T` in my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `typename` keyword anytime you have a dependent type (such as `ContainerType<T>::iterator`):

```
template <typename T, class ContainerType>
typename ContainerType<T>::iterator elementIteratorAt(ContainerType<T> container, size_t index)
```

Comment: Makes sense but doesn't help. Same error.